# WooCommerce ajax cart page - Disable "remove item" (red icon "X" button)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

In WooCommerce ajax cart page, I have tried to detach default javascript event for removing added items (the little red icon with a cross) using:

```
$(".remove").off("click");
```

Or

```
$(".remove").unbind("click");
```

But it didn't work.

The main reason why I am trying to do this is because, in header, I have a  custom menu cart icon with product number notification on it. And I can't either get this notification number updated through WooCommerce ajax, but only refreshing page.

How can I disable this javascript event?
Or How can I make my notification script working with ajax?

Here is my menucart code:

```php
<div id="expanded-menucart"> 

<?php  

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

    ?>

    <div class="one-menucart-item">

        <?php 

        $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $product_subtotal = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity']), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
        $quantity = $_product->get_stock_quantity();
        $antal = $cart_item['variation']['attribute_antal']; 
        $productid = $cart_item['product_id']; 

        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" class="remove, cart-remove" title="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
            esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
            __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
            esc_attr( $product_id ),
            esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
            ), $cart_item_key ); 

        echo $thumbnail; ?>
        <a id="<?php $productid; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink($productid); ?>"> <?php echo $cart_item['data']->post->post_title;?></a><br><br><?php
        echo $antal;
        echo $product_subtotal;?><br>

    </div><?php
}
?>
<?php global $woocommerce; ?>

    <p>TOTAL:
        <a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a></p><br>

    <?php if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() != 0 ) { ?>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="menucart-checkout">
                    <a href="<?php get_home_url(); ?>/fcb/checkout">TILL CHECKOUTEN</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

    </div>
```

External source on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/7rXuBQPj

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec ! :) I removed menucart icon from my cartpage and everything seems okay now. Thank you one more time!

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is only when you are **in cart page** because in this case you have 2 carts:

- You have a mini cart kind of in your header (with notification, but without quantity buttons).
- You have in page content your normal cart (without that notifications, but with quantity buttons).

> So they are in conflict and that is normal. You will have to chose between them.

---

**The question:** Are you really needing this mini-cart as it is on cart page?

**2 solutions:**

1. To have a **light mini cart version** on cart page (avoiding conflicts and live refreshing items (ajax remove)) only with item count, for example. Or you could **disable** it completely for cart page. You could use the conditional **`is_cart()`** for this purpose.
2. To bypass cart page (much more difficult) extending missing functionalities to your actual mini-cart:

   - Adding quantity buttons by items line
   - Adding optional coupon field functionality

In case 2 you will have to redirect customer to checkout, what is a classic behavior on some WooCommerce shops.