# WooCommerce Cart Page: Remove Item Button move place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to ask how to move this Remove Item Button on the right side of cart page besides total. [Image Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWpJM.png)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288722/how-to-modify-woocommerce-cart-checkout-pages-main-theme-portion - The non chosen answers also brings the idea on how it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify WooCommerce cart, checkout pages (main theme portion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288722/how-to-modify-woocommerce-cart-checkout-pages-main-theme-portion)

Comment: @caiovisk if you update the theme, the button will be back to default of the WooCommerce. Is there no way for CSS or JS to do it?

Comment: There is a way on CSS by positioning your button as Absolute, but the right way to do is override the Woocommerce template files... https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce ajax cart page - Disable "remove item" (red icon "X" button)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338825/woocommerce-ajax-cart-page-disable-remove-item-red-icon-x-button)

Comment: a css grid solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64497775/544503

Answer (score 1):

It will be fairly simple if you just override the cart.php file of the Woocommerce plugin. Just override the file and rearrange the table columns as you want

Answer (score 0):

Save below code as cart.php and put the file under your active theme folder in and as woocommerce/cart/cart.php

```
<?php defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' ); ?>
<form class="woocommerce-cart-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

        <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive cart woocommerce-cart-form__contents" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th class="product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <th class="product-price"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <th class="product-quantity"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <th class="product-subtotal"><?php esc_html_e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                                    <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); ?>

                <?php
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                    if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $cart_item['quantity'] > 0 && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', true, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ) {
                        $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                        ?>
                        <tr class="woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item <?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_class', 'cart_item', $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) ); ?>">


                            <td class="product-thumbnail">
                            <?php
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            } else {
                                printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            }
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                            if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                            } else {
                                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                            }

                            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                            // Meta data.
                            echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                            // Backorder notification.
                            if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                                echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                            }
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                                ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <?php
                            if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                                $product_quantity = sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $cart_item_key );
                            } else {
                                $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input( array(
                                    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                    'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                    'max_value'    => $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                                    'min_value'    => '0',
                                    'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                                ), $_product, false );
                            }

                            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                            ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="product-subtotal" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Totalllll', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                                <?php
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                                ?>
                            </td>
                                                    <td class="product-remove">
                                <?php
                                    // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
                                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
                                        '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                                        esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                        __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                        esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                    ), $cart_item_key );
                                ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                }
                ?>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_contents' ); ?>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6" class="actions">

                        <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
                            <div class="coupon">
                                <label for="coupon_code"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="submit" class="button" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <button type="submit" class="button" name="update_cart" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update cart', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>

                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart', 'woocommerce-cart-nonce' ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>
    </form>

    <div class="cart-collaterals">
        <?php

            do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart' ); ?>
```